# Installation CiviHR

Tags: installation, civihr

I would like to install CiviHR and design the data base, but I need support and training for tha. Is there any organisation or individual in the Netherlands that can provide that support?

Answer (score 1):

we do not have any experience with CiviHR but we have been supporting CiviCRM in The Netherlands for quite some time now :-) Drop me a line at erik.hommel@civicoop.org?